# How to sort and display videos from mysql db

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sorting, performance

How do I efficiently sort videos that users have uploaded?

I am storing the actual videos in a separate file, and their info in a MySQL database.

Say I want to sort by "date uploaded", how do I go about doing this?

I have a column for date uploaded. There could potentially be millions of records to sort, but I will only probably display the top 10 on the website.

Comment: What exactly is your question about - how to sort queried data? How to run a query in the first place?

Comment: @coder: you could query the data using SELECT*FROM table ORDER BY uploadDate..

Comment: @coder have you tried `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ...`

Comment: @Benny: thanks for your reply. Is ORDER BY good for a huge database?

Comment: @james: SELECT TOP 10 gives an error.

Comment: @James, `TOP 10` is TSQL or Oracle syntax, MySQL uses `limit`

Comment: @Johan oops! your right `limit` it is. not having MySql with me I didn't check but its not a hard keyword to find. I was just wondering if it had been tried. Seemed an obvious first choice.

Comment: @James, it's one of those idiotic fall-outs of the ANSI SQL'92 standard fiasco. It would have been trivial  to fix a standard keyword for this, but .....

Comment: @Johan yeah but who wants to standardise things ... that would make it too easy `</sarcasm>`. Thankfully I only dabble in SQL. I'm sure one day there will be another push to standardise these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I want to sort by "date uploaded"

```
SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC LIMIT 10;
```

It's better and faster to just select the fields you need:

```
SELECT filenames FROM video ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Make sure you put an index on `date_uploaded`.
If you use InnoDB, put an index on filenames as well, because then InnoDB can use a covering index and does not need to read the database itself.

**Links:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html
http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/

Comment: Thanks for the useful info and links Johan!

Comment: @coder, you're quite welcome. Please note that on SO it is expected that you include some details on your database (table layout etc) and details about things that you've tried. If you don't include those your question will likely get downvoted (this is what happened to you) and you may not get the quantity and quality of answers that you need. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm a newbie, and wasn't quite sure why I got downvoted. I'll include code next time.